# media resize/crop possibilities?

Tags: functions, images, cropping, media-settings

Under admin panel -> media settings
there are no minimal width option for thumb or other image modes

ex: I would like to crop image widthout distortion ->
height 124px and minimum-width 124px and maximum-width 500px

So it doesnt allow images to crop below 124px and over 500px but holding always 124px height

How to make it happend? some script for functions.php, some plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I use the plugin [Simple Image Sizes](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-image-sizes/). If you do not want to use a plugin you have to use the function [add_image_size](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size)